# What type of differentiation is this? Could someone please explain it to me

Tags: derivatives

I'm working with this formula (Insurance problem 1), Im at the first step but I dont quite get which differentiation rule they used, I'm happy to start reading up on it, but hoping someone could explain the process to me and also if you know where I could get a tutorial on it too, it would really be helpful, thank you :)
[image: Insurance Question]

Comment: You need to specify which variables depend on $x$ and which do not.  It would appear that $u$ does because we see $u'$ but none of the others do.  Please make it clear.

Comment: From the looks of it, $u$ is a function...as such, they are just using the chain rule: i.e.,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: @David:  I was just looking at that.  I think you are right.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using these lecture slides http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic470837.files/lecture11small.pdf

which are similar to my microeconomics unit, I dont have a maths background and just getting a bit confused.

Comment: Then yes, what I said appears coherent with the slides. $u(\cdot)$ is a utility function. I will give a answer below with a few more details and a link to some outside material.

Comment: Even if you are confused, the difference between variables and functions is quite important.  When I first read the problem I thought $u$ was a variable and the notes were badly wrong.  The parenthesized stuff after $u$ would be multiplying it, not an argument.  **Context, please**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if we have a composition of two differentiable functions, say $u$ and $g$, and for simplicity lets say both functions have their domain and range on the reals, i.e., we have $$u(g(x))$$ where $$u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$$ then $$\frac{d}{dx}u(g(x)) = u'(g(x))g'(x).$$ In your case, this rule is used in both terms. In the first term, we can let $$g(x) = w-qx-d+x$$ and $u(\cdot)$ be some differentiable function. Then, $$g'(x) = 0-q-0+1 = 1-q.$$ Hence $$\frac{d}{dx}u(g(x)) = u'(w-qx-d+x)(1-q).$$ Hopefully you can take it from there, if not, here's the link to the Kahn Academy videos: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/product-quotient-chain-rules-ab/chain-rule-ab/v/chain-rule-introduction

Comment: Thanks David, really appreciate it, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears $u$ is a function (why didn't you make that clear?) and they are using the chain rule.  The chain rule says $\frac d{dx}u(g(x))=u'(g(x))g'(x)$  Taking the first term in your expression, $g(x)=w-qx-d+x$, so $g'(x)=1-q$

Comment: Thanks Ross, I'm learning as I go along, i will include more information next time, but thank you for your help :)